# Add white dots to a sweater

Tags: clothing

So I bought a 100% cotton sweater for a Christmas party, except it's borderline Christmas.  I wanted to add perfect little white dots to it so that it looked like it was snowing.

I had a couple of ideas, but I don't want to do them because they could come out bad and ruin the sweater (Well, have it come out not as planned)

- *My first idea was bleach*.  The problem with this is, bleach can be absorbed by the sweater and end up bleaching not perfect little circles that could look like snow.  Another thought was that it might not bleach it completely white, it could turn out to be a faded blue color instead of pure white.
- *My second thought was paint*.  The huge problem with this is you would definitely be able to tell they are painted on white dots, because they won't look like cotton at all.

So I want a way to have white dots on my sweater that look basically like they were sewn in when the sweater was made.

I'm trying to keep this as cheap as possible also, I bought the sweater for $3 but I want it too look good too. I'm open for any solution though! If there is a good enough solution that involves more $$ but will come out perfect, I'm game for that!

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to find inexpensive white buttons and sew them on. Those would be perfectly circular, of course, and would take just a little effort on your part. The trick would be positioning them so they look snowy.

Another option would be to buy an iron-on t-shirt transfer sheet at an art store. They make opaque white sheets that can printed on with a home printer, and then ironed onto a shirt. If the shirt is smooth enough (not cable-knit, for example), you could cut small circles out of the white sheet and iron them on, following the instructions on the package.

Comment: To build on BrettFromLA's answer, you could find any white clothing/cloth that could be discarded, cut that up into the circular shapes you need, then sew on them onto the jumper.

Comment: @techytimB Clever! I also thought you were going to say that if you found another shirt that had white buttons, you could scavenge those and sew them on.

Answer (score 2):

How about sewing on [snowflake shaped sequins](https://www.google.com/search?q=snowflake%20sequins&tbm=isch).

Alternately you could cut out dots or shapes from [iron on transfer paper or tape](https://www.google.com/search?q=iron-on%20transfers%20OR%20tape%20white&tbm=isch) that is used to transfer inkjet printed images or for writing names on.

A [white paint marker or correcting pen](https://www.google.com/search?q=white%20correcting%20OR%20paint%20pen&tbm=isch) might be a possible solution.

These will be of varying durability and esthetic quality but something should be available in your area or if you have the time you could surely find something to purchase from one of the internet stores.

Answer (score 1):

If silvery would be acceptable, a number (perhaps 4-5 pairs) of plain stainless ear piercing studs (around $5/pair last time I checked) could be pushed through and fastened on the inside with their included clasps.  These would require wearing something under the sweater, to protect your skin from the stud ends and clasps, but the studs could be removed and shouldn't leave a visible hole.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about the sweater to be honest. I bought it for $3 dollars. I'm going to edit I want to keep the solution as cheap as possible. It does sound like a neat idea though. As long as the solution I get comes out looking great, that's what I really want.

Answer (score 0):

You could also easily stick cotton balls or cotton pads on.  I wouldn't count on the bleach since it might spread and not look like snow.